# Web Application: Server File Copy - Progress Tracking

Tags: javascript, php, apache, web-applications, file-copying

I have a web application that allows limited file manipulation on the web server. The users can upload, download, copy, and move files to various locations within their file space.

What possibilities do I have, if I wish to track progress of file copying operation from one location to another on the server?

Currently, when I copy a large file (about 1 GB), for couple of seconds nothing happens, until the file copy is finished. During those times, users will definitely be confused, whether their function actually is taking place. I want to show progress bar to inform the user, that this operation is in progress.

I need to show percentage about how much data has been already copied, as it is higher value progress information than just informing, that copying is in progress without percentage info(say a rotating icon with info: Copying in progress.).

Currently, I use php [copy()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.copy.php) function. Should I implement my own read/write function in PHP?

My planned configuration:

- HTML5
- PHP
- JavaScript
- Linux Ubuntu
- Apache Web Server
- MySQL

Thank you in advance.